# How do sessions and cookies work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, cookies, devise

I have been using Devise for a while to handle authentication on my Rails apps, but never really understood how it works. Because Devise also uses the session storage config set on Rails, I'm assuming this is a question on session handling with Rails.

Basically, I'm an auth newbie. I've read a few articles about authentication but most deal with abstracted libraries (they talk about engines, middle ware, etc) that don't make much sense to me. I'm really looking for lower level details.

Here's what I know so far..

I know about cookies and sessions. Cookies are strings stored on client-side which is used to maintain session across multiple HTTP requests.

**Here's my basic understanding of authentication (please correct me if I'm wrong):**

1. When user logs in, we send the SSL encrypted request to the server. If the credentials are valid, we save a random string called session id on the database (or any other data store) as the valid session id associated with a user id. This session id changes for each login/logout of the user.
2. After saving that session id on our data store, we return a response that asks the browser to set a cookie with the session id. This session id along with the user id would then be sent for successive request to the domain until it expires. For each request, our server would check the session id on the headers and verify if that session id is valid for that user id. If it is, then consider that user authenticated.

**Here are my questions:**

1. I've read that by default starting from Rails 2, it now uses CookieStore (instead of SessionStore) which generates session hashes with SHA512 (instead of session ids), and all this is stored on a cookie which means multiple user id's can literally have the same session hash and it would just work fine. It seems to me that this is a very dangerous thing, exposing a large number of hashes with a single secret key stored on the server and basing your entire authentication system based on this key. Is there a real world large scale application that uses hashing instead of storing server side session id's?
2. On the topic of storing active session id's on server side, I've also read that you can switch to use different kinds of session storage for Rails. Based on this, I've heard of systems moving authentication systems out as services and using auth tokens instead. What's an auth token and how does it differ from a session id?
3. Seems like I can just keep guessing a random string (for both hashing and server side sessions) to grab an existing session. Is there a way to protect against this? Is it normal to use more values stored on a cookie? (such as the username, real name or even another hash for authentication)

I know I'm asking a lot but I believe this will be useful for people like me who do not understand authentication and will be very useful to get a solid foundation about the topic.

Comment: This is a very good question, and the obscurity of Devise has long been a barrier for adoption in our company. Will follow this closely.

Comment: The hash that is generated is not merely composed of the logged on user's attributes.  i.ei. you couldn't generate a duplicate SHA1 hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've read that by default starting from Rails 2, it now uses
>   CookieStore (instead of SessionStore) which generates session hashes
>   with SHA512 (instead of session ids), and all this is stored on a
>   cookie which means multiple user id's can literally have the same
>   session hash and it would just work fine. It seems to me that this is
>   a very dangerous thing, exposing a large number of hashes with a
>   single secret key stored on the server and basing your entire
>   authentication system based on this key.

Yeah, it seems scary at first blush, but I'm not sure what the danger really is. In Rails 4, session data is encrypted using PBKBF2, and then *signed* with your session secret. This signing helps detect if the contents of the encrypted session have been tampered and the server will reject the session if it detects tampering.

https://cowbell-labs.com/2013-04-10-decrypt-rails-4-session.html

If someone gains access to the session token (which is used to sign the session cookie), you likely have much bigger problems on your hands than end-users attempting to impersonate the wrong user.

> Is there a real world large scale application that uses hashing 
>   instead of storing server side session id's?

I honestly don't know the answer to this one offhand, but I suspect that the fact that this is the "default" for Rails means that there are more than a handful of sites out there using cookie session stores.

> On the topic of storing active session id's on server side, I've also
>   read that you can switch to use different kinds of session storage for
>   Rails. Based on this, I've heard of systems moving authentication
>   systems out as services and using auth tokens instead. What's an auth
>   token and how does it differ from a session id?

I'm doing this on a server now - basically a random hash is generated when a user authenticates, and that hash is stored, encrypted and signed, in the cookie. The cookie hash is a key into a server-side datastore (in my case Redis, but it can be in a relational database or memcache or whatever you like), and the actual session data is the stored server-side mapped to that key. This leaves less of your session data in the hands of the client were people could potentially decrypt and analyze it, so it's generally a bit safer.

> Seems like I can just keep guessing a random string (for both hashing
>   and server side sessions) to grab an existing session. Is there a way
>   to protect against this? Is it normal to use more values stored on a
>   cookie? (such as the username, real name or even another hash for
>   authentication)

Yes, you could do that, but it would take a very very long time. You would also need to guess how to sign the newly tampered cookie data so that it'd match what the server expects to see on its side, and it's signed with a pretty large key.

I really don't think there's much alternative for persisting authentication state to using cookies (I suppose HTML5 Local Storage would work if you're feeling exotic and don't care much about legacy browser support).

Comment: ah..that makes sense, forgot that it actually encrypts the hash which makes it a lot more difficult. I'm still a bit confused on the token based auth vs session ids. From your explanation, I'm guessing you're referring to token based authentication? so what's the difference between token based and just using a session id stored somewhere (it's also mapped to session information right?)

Comment: the "session token" I was talking about is the server-side "key" that's used to sign the session. For authentication, you usually would just store some sort of user ID in the session itself, which would either be the signed cookie, or would be server side using a session key you store in the cookie.